# Auto Increment CompanyID field when entering data with a form in sql/visual studio

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2012

I am setting up an inventory database using SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2015 and am creating the add new customer form.

I have setup the table using an auto increment on `CompanyID` that starts at 1000 and auto increments by 1. I can manually enter table data and my auto increment is fine very basic.

I have started to code a form to insert data into the Customers table but am stuck on how to get this functioning correctly. I need a way of entering data using the form whilst having the `CompanyID` field auto increment when the user clicks save.

Below is my code, any help greatly appreciated.

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SNZ-HYPERV02;Initial Catalog=Signals;Integrated Security=True"

End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    con.Open()

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(("INSERT INTO Customers VALUES('" &
                              CName.Text & "', '" &
                              A1.Text & "', '" &
                              A2.Text & "', '" &
                              A3.Text & "', '" &
                              Suburb.Text & "', '" &
                              City.Text & "', '" &
                              PCode.Text & "', '" &
                              Area.Text & "', '" &
                              Country.Text & "', '" &
                              CellPh.Text & "', '" &
                              Fax.Text & "', '" &
                              Email.Text & "', '" &
                              Website.Text & "', '" &
                              SContact.Text & "', '" &
                              SPhone.Text & "', '" &
                              SEmail.Text & "', '" &
                              AContact.Text & "', '" &
                              APhone.Text & "', '" &
                              AEmail.Text & "', '" &
                              SPerson.Text & "')"), con)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    con.Close()

    MsgBox("Record Successfully Entered", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "SUCCESS")

    CName.Clear()
    A1.Clear()
    A2.Clear()
    A3.Clear()
    Suburb.Clear()
    City.Clear()
    PCode.Clear()
    Area.Clear()
    Country.Clear()
    CellPh.Clear()
    Fax.Clear()
    Email.Clear()
    Website.Clear()
    SContact.Clear()
    SPhone.Clear()
    SEmail.Clear()
    AContact.Clear()
    APhone.Clear()
    AEmail.Clear()
    SPerson.Clear()

    CName.Focus()

End Sub
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `SQL Command`, specific the field (except the `Company ID`) you need to insert.  Without specific the field name, SQL will think you want to insert value for all fields

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(("INSERT INTO Customers (fieldnameA, fieldnameB ...) VALUES('" &
                          CName.Text & "', '" &
                          A1.Text & "', '" &
                          A2.Text & "', '" &
                          A3.Text & "', '" &
                          Suburb.Text & "', '" &
                          City.Text & "', '" &
                          PCode.Text & "', '" &
                          Area.Text & "', '" &
                          Country.Text & "', '" &
                          CellPh.Text & "', '" &
                          Fax.Text & "', '" &
                          Email.Text & "', '" &
                          Website.Text & "', '" &
                          SContact.Text & "', '" &
                          SPhone.Text & "', '" &
                          SEmail.Text & "', '" &
                          AContact.Text & "', '" &
                          APhone.Text & "', '" &
                          AEmail.Text & "', '" &
                          SPerson.Text & "')"), con)
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you so much for taking the time to look at this, I have taken your advice and changed the SQL Command and the form is working perfectly. I only hope i can be as helpful as you on return sometime :)

Comment: Glad that I can help you, please mark it as answer if that can solve your problem, thanks

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Hi Marc_s, Thanks for your feedback here - Obviously SQL injection attacks need to be taken into account and as i am relatively new to programming I will look into this - kind regards